# Error message when trying to open a sample project

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am getting the following error message when trying to open a sample project - CSVSample.

Any idea what am I missing. I did install a lot of plugins recently but not sure if I am still missing something for this project to work.

> Error :  org/springframework/jms/support/converter/MessageConverter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be a missing [jms](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMSSampler/) plugin

Comment: You can accept the answer by clicking V sign to the left